# Why can't I access this public property of ClientBase?

Tags: c#

I have a proxy class called `MyProxyClass` which has been auto-generated through `svcutil.exe` around a SOAP web-service WSDL. This proxy class is an implementation of the abstract `System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<TChannel>` class:

```
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
public partial class MyProxyClass : System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<MyProxyClassPortType>, MyProxyClassPortType
{
    // 60,000 lines of auto-generated code
}
```

`System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<TChannel>` defines the following public property:

```
public ServiceEndpoint Endpoint
{
    get
    {
        //brevity
    }
}
```

However, when I create a new instance of this proxy class

```
var _client = new MyProxyClass();
```

I am unable to see the `Endpoint` property through intellisense. If I try to access `Endpoint` through `_client.Endpoint`, the compiler gives the corresponding error of `'MyProxyClass' does not contain a definition for 'Endpoint' and no extension method 'Endpoint' accepting a first argument of type 'MyProxyClass' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

However, the following reflection method works just fine, and the property is returned as I expect:

```
ServiceEndpoint endpoint = 
(ServiceEndpoint)typeof(ClientBase<MyProxyClassPortType>).GetProperty("Endpoint").GetValue(_client);
```

So why can't I access this publicly accessible (recall that the particular overload of `GetProperty` only searches for public properties) property in the normal way?

Comment: If the get was empty, the code would not compile.

Comment: Can you provide a more complete piece of code?

Comment: Yes, but what else do you want to see?

Comment: Are you sure the `MyProxyClass` you are calling is the correct one. You may have two of the same named class in different namespaces. (I have made that mistake myself with svcutil generated classes and putting code in a partal class in the wrong namespace than what svcutil generated)

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Thank you, but that is not the case. This is a self-contained project with no references to other namespaces within the solution.

Comment: It can still be self contained and still have namespace errors `namespace MyProject.Services` vs `namespace MyProject.Service` or similar. What we are trying to tell you is what you have shown us will not cause the issue, so the issue comes from something you have not shown us. We don't know what else to see because we don't know what the problem is, all we know is it is not here.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I appreciate the advice, but I am absolutely certain that this is a red herring. Remember that I can access the property through reflection, and all other functionality of the class behaves as expected. Furthermore, this project contains only two classes, one of which is the proxy. I am baffled as well, hence posting the SO question, so please keep the suggestions coming.

Comment: Show us how your proxy class is defined.

Comment: @Amy I have edited in that information. Thank you.

Comment: Check the auto-generated code in the derived class. Does it redefine a *new* property named `Endpoint` which shadows the parent's property?

Comment: @AvnerShahar-Kashtan Good guess, but no - it does not have a property named "Endpoint". Also, if it did, I would expect to be able to get that *new* property through its public accessor - but the compiler claims that no property called `Endpoint` exists at all!

Comment: @NWard Well, it might have added a private/protected property with the same name that hides the public one. But no, not in this case.

Comment: @AvnerShahar-Kashtan I would have expected this behavior in that case: https://dotnetfiddle.net/IBVSab Thank you for the suggestion though! This is a weird one.

Comment: Does project in which you're attempting to access the `Endpoint` property have a reference to `System.ServiceModel`?

Comment: @Amy Yes, it does. Removing the reference leads to a compiler error in the reflection method when I call `typeof(ClientBase[...])`. Good guess though, thanks!

Comment: I don't suppose you could put together a small project that demonstrates this issue and stick it up on Github?  We won't be able to solve this as is.

Comment: @Amy Ugh, thank you, creating that small project revealed my (simple and extremely stupid) error, which was not present in my OP because I did not literally transcribe my code. The issue was that my variable was typed to the *interface*, not to the *implementation*, and only the implementation subclassed ClientBase. If you would like to write an answer I will happy accept it so that you get points. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your variable is typed to a concrete class and not an interface.